# Update ObservableCollection without Clearing it?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I was trying to bind data to datagrid using observablecollection and was wondering how i can update the collection without clearing it. 
The new data is provided to me every 500ms-1s.

What is currently have is i clear the Observable collection everytime and re-add the items using new data.
Although this works fine and cant see any flickering on the UI but i was wondering if there is a proper way to update the collection.

```
    private ObservableCollection<AC> m_Label = new ObservableCollection<AC>();
    public ObservableCollection<AC> Label
    {
        get => m_Label;
        private set => Set(ref m_Label, value);
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...
    Label = ThreadInvoker.Instance.RunByUiThread(() => {
                Label.Clear();
                return Label; });

    {
        //parse and convert data that is provided every 500 milisecond
        ...
        ...

        Label = ThreadInvoker.Instance.RunByUiThread(() => {
                Label.Add(new AC(pass parameters obtained from the new data);
                return Label; });
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
            <Label Content="Customer"/>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Label}"  Name="dgCustomer" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding AlcoveId}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding StateDescription}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="OrderID" Binding="{Binding OrderID}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
   </StackPanel>
```

Comment: You forgot to explain why are you clearing it? Do you replace complete collection with new data? Then why you say "add" ?

Comment: If it's like a scrolling ticker type thing where you add new items and remove the old ones then a linked list would suit you better

Comment: My guess is that you're not actually changing the collection, but the items in it (for example, if you're displaying 20 stock prices, there's always 20 - they're just different prices).  In that case, I would leave the ObservableCollection alone, and just update the data in each element (presumably that's what AC is?)

Comment: @Sinatr
I'm clearing it because the whole code is executed periodically and if i dont clear it then the collection just keeps adding the same items.

Comment: @pm_2
yes the collection isnt going to change, just the data in each element.
So you are saying just add the AC items once to the collection and update each AC item

Comment: Yes - I've tried to illustrate that in an answer.  I would question is you really /need/ to update every second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the collection isn't going to change, you might be better just updating the individual classes; for example:

```
class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public decimal StockPrice {get;set;} // ToDo: Call notify property changed
}

. . .

ObservableCollection<MyData> Data;

. . .

foreach (var d in Data)
{
    d.StockPrice = Rnd.Next(...);
}
```

Comment: So the "MyData" would be AC in my case?

Comment: Yes - I purposely used a different class name because I don't know what `AC` is.

Comment: How would I bind the AC items to a datagrid.
My AC class has
-ID
-Description
-Order#

Comment: If you post your XAML in the question, I might be able to give you a specific answer

Comment: Looking at your XAML, I believe the data should reflect in the UI as you update the underlying data - are you saying it doesn't?  I would also, again, suggest that you don't need to update so frequently, looking at the data description

Comment: how come you have a class named Data and ObservableCollection with the same name?

Comment: I’ve changed it - but the code is for illustration purposes only :-)

Comment: for this i guess i would have to add all the (MyData) items in the collection first.
what if i dont know the number of items to be added until runtime?

Comment: Just add them all during initialisation.  You shouldn’t need to know the size of the collection - you might find you get a performance improvement by loading your items into a temporary collection and transfer to the observable collection once it’s loaded